# Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class

Tags: php

i get this error

Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in user.php on line 248
this is the line

```
  function loadUser($userID)
  {
  global $db;   
    $res = $db->getrow("SELECT * FROM `{$this->dbTable}` WHERE `{$this->tbFields['userID']}` = '".$this->escape($userID)."' LIMIT 1");
    if ( !$res )
        return false;
    $this->userData = $res;
    $this->userID = $userID;
    $_SESSION[$this->sessionVariable] = $this->userID;
    return true;
  }
```

see

```
var_dump($_SESSION); 

array(1) { ["user"]=> &object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (12) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(11) "jooria_user" ["dbTable"]=> string(5) "users" ["sessionVariable"]=> string(4) "user" } }
```

Comment: there are several lines on line 248?

Comment: Can you point out in your code what line 248 is?

Answer (score 5):

Is this an object stored in session? Have you declared your class before retrieving the object from session?

In any case, my guess is that you're missing a class declaration somewhere.

**EDIT:** Your class `jooria_user` is not declared before use. That is why you get that error.

Say you have this:

```
<?php
session_start();
class A {}
$a = new A;
$_SESSION['A'] = $a;
```

Then you try to access it in this script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$a = $_SESSION['A'];
var_dump($a);

/* outputs:
      object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (1) {
        ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
        string(1) "A"
      }
*/
```

Now if you do that instead:

```
<?php
class A {} // declares the class here
session_start();
$a = $_SESSION['A'];
var_dump($a);

/* outputs:
      object(A)#1 (1) {
      }
*/
```

Comment: how i can do that unserialize($_SESSION)

Comment: Sorry I was editing while you were posting. See my revised answer. In other words: `jooria_user` has to be declared in the script that accesses it from session.

Comment: no i save the session with ingeter i dont know what all this happedn

Comment: Apparently you aren't. $_SESSION['user'] is an object of type `jooria_user`, from what we can see from your var_dump.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the provided function-argument `$userID` is an object and the error occurs here:

```
$this->escape($userID)
```

(I don't see any further string-operations that could force such an error).

So check out what's the argument you call `loadUser()` with.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd make sure all `{ }` braces have pairs in the right place. A `}` missing from the last line would be my guess.